# Выезжающий блок

Tags: javascript, html, css3, sass

Хотел бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на некую кнопку(или любой другой элемент) один из двух блоков(которые находятся внутри другого) уезжал за экран, после чего второй блок занимал бы 100% ширины и вполтную к левому краю экрана появлялась линия, при нажатии на которую всё возвращалось на места.
Вот что я пытался сделать. Не получается сделать так, чтобы чёрная линия "прилипла" к блоку и когда блок уезжает, она оставалась  на краю экрана.
Html код:

```
<section class="main">
<div class="open" id="open"></div>
      <div class="main_projects" id="projects">
        // контент
      </div>
      <div class="main_about" id="about">
        // контент
      </div>
    </section>
```

sass:

```
.open
    float:left
    transition: 0.6s
    width: 17px
    height: 100%
    background-color: #000
.main
    display: flex
    width: 100%
    height: 1680px
    &_projects
        transition: 0.6s
        padding: 53px 28px 32px 28px
        margin: 0
        width: 938px
        height: 100%
        background: #002535
    &_about
        padding-top: 115px
        width: 100%
        background: #fff
        display: flex
        flex-direction: column
        align-items: center
        
.rotate
    transform: translateX(-1000px)
    width: 0
    transition: 0.6s
```

Js:

```
document.getElementById("open").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("projects").classList.toggle("rotate");
};
```

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь за формулировку данного вопроса. Написал как мне показалось наиболее удачную

Comment: не понятно причины почему не получилось? незнание js? или просто нету понятия как этого добится? если второе можно сделать за несколько шагов не обязательно что все достигалось одним классом 'rotate'

Comment: скорее и первое и второе, js  у меня на довольно низком уровне, поэтому я пытаюсь больше практиковаться в нём

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так?? я пока что js не трогал только css

```js
const open = document.querySelector('.open')
const mainProjects = document.querySelector('.main_projects')

open.addEventListener('click',e => {
  mainProjects.classList.toggle('rotate')
})
```

```css
body{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
.open {
        position: relative;
    transition: 0.6s;
    min-width: 17px;
    height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        z-index: 2;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
        height: 1680px;
        border: 1px solid red;
}

.main_projects {
    transition: 0.6s;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #002535;
}

.main_about {
    padding-top: 115px;
        width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.rotate {
    transform: translateX(-1000px);
    width: 0;
    transition: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
    <section class="main">
<div class="open" id="open"></div>
      <div class="main_projects" id="projects">
        // контент
      </div>
      <div class="main_about" id="about">
        // контент
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое